# selenium js webdriver.By

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am having an issue with selenium js

I have created my components in json like:

```
"usernameInputField": {
    "selector": {
      "xpath": "//*[@id='username']"
    }
  }
```

and I am calling webdriver :

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

using the data like this:

```
console.log(webdriver.By.xpath("//*[@id='username']"));
```

**it calls correctly**

however when I try to run  `console.log(webdriver.By(usernameInputField.selector));`

**I get an error** (`TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'`)

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular `findElement` directly without having to use the `By` "class":

```
driver.findElement(usernameInputField.selector);
```

Comment: thankyou I just realized I misread the documentation, I just assumed that everything to select components would need to be done by the webdriver